# How to index in to arrays in PogoScript?

Tags: javascript, pogoscript

I can't figure out how to index in to arrays using a variable in PogoScript.

Constants seem to work:

```
xs = ['beef','wellington','ensemble']
console.log (xs.1) // prints wellington
```

But variables don't:

```
xs = ['beef','wellington','ensemble']
i = 1
console.log (xs.i) // prints undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the same way you do it in normal JavaScript: `x[i]`.

Comment: I tried that, but you get `xs([i])` in the compiled JavaScript :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this problem last week couldn't figure it out myself either.

I created a ticket on the [PogoScript GitHub](https://github.com/featurist/pogoscript/issues/7) page and got an answer there.

You need to place brackets around the variable to index into the array:

```
xs = ['beef','wellington','ensemble']
i = 1
console.log (xs.(i)) // prints wellington
```

Also the [Cheat Sheet](http://pogoscript.org/cheatsheet.html) has now been updated with this info!